# .net table in email body

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know how to send this information on a table. This is the body of the email, the app is currently working fine, just need to convert this info into a 2 row table.

```
email.Body = "Company Name: " + CompanyName.Value + "<br />";
email.Body += "Customer Code: " + ClientCode.Value + "<br />";
email.Body += "Country: " + Country.Value + "<br />";
email.Body += "Your Full Name: " + FullContactName.Value + "<br />";
email.Body += "Position in your Company: " + ContactTitle.Value + "<br />";
email.Body += "Phone Number: " + PhoneNumber.Value + "<br />";
email.Body += "Email Address: " + ContactEmail.Value + "<br />";
```

I need just a simple 2 row table, can't seem to be able to do it correctly on my own, I'm totally new to .net, C# and/or asp, thx a lot!

Comment: You would use HTML format and build a `<table>`

Comment: This isn't really `C#` or `.NET` related, it's basic HTML. `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` ?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Using a simple html table didnt work and the app stopped working, its a form in a website that gathers this info and sends it over on a email to the customer service rep, its currently doing that I just need to modify it so they would get this info in a table, to facilitate their job

Comment: @gunr2171 come on man I just needed help with the structure of an email, I´m not asking anyone to write a program for me, don't even need to copy the entire app's code here I just wanted to know how to insert that little code inside a table, I don't really think you need more info than the one I provided, but if that were the case I'll be more than happy to provide it, someone already answered below with exactly what I needed, I know this was a noob question, anyway thx for the help

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually going to make one recommendation that sending this content in an email is probably not the best idea due to it being plain text PII, but as far as how:

```
email.Body = "<table>" + 
              "<tr>" +
               "<td>Company Name</td>" +
               "<td>Customer Code</td>" +
               "<td>Country</td>" + 
               "<td>Your Full Name</td>" +
               "<td>Position in your Company</td>" +
               "<td>Phone Number</td>" +
               "<td>Email Address</td>" +
              "</tr>" +
              "<tr>" +
               "<td>" + CompanyName.Value + "</td>" +
               "<td>" + ClientCode.Value + "</td>" +
               ...
              "</tr>"
             "</table>";
```

structuring it like that would probably be the cleanest way. Not sure how the Variable.Value is being constructed, but if you can move this into an object (ie CompanyClient), may be worthwhile to put something like this into a ObjectTypeToTable(obj) method that returns a similar string to reduce the amount of code you're staring at when you have to troubleshoot something in the future (or a single area to modify later if you reuse that call in something else).

Comment: Thx a lot this is exactly what I needed, to see the structure, I know the tags are the same "table", "td", "tr", but I didn't know how to parse them in a email.body first time ever using email.body, anyway thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

There's an ASP.NET table control that you can interact with to generate an HTML table. You just create it using code like this (I'm probably over-simplifying):

```
Table tbl = new Table();
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
tc.Text = "Test";
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
```

This is probably more than you need for something like this since you can very easily create the structure with strings, but down the road it could come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an HTML body like:

```
email.Body = "<table><tr>"
                 "<th>Company Name</th>" + 
                 "<th>Customer Code</th>" +
                 "<th>Country</th>" +
                 "<th>Your Full Name</th>" +
                 "<th>Position in your Company</th>" +
                 "<th>Phone Number</th>" +
                 "<th>Email Address</th>" +
              "<tr/><tr>" +
                 "<td>" + CompanyName.Value + "</td>" + 
                 "<td>" + ClientCode.Value + "</td>"+
                 "<td>" + Country.Value + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + FullContactName.Value + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + ContactTitle.Value + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + PhoneNumber.Value + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + ContactEmail.Value + "</td>" +
              "</tr></table>";
```